# Good way to construct derived class in java

Tags: java, oop, constructor

I have some classes that have outline like this

```
class A{
    //class A elements
    A(typeA1 A1, typeA2 A2, ....){//initialize elements}
}

class B extends A{
    //class B elements
    B(typeA1 A1, typeA2 A2,...... typeB1 B1, typeB2 B2, ....)
    {
        super(typeA1 A1, typeA2 A2,......);
        //initialize B elements
    }
}
```

What I am doing to construct B class is pass arguments of both A and B to B's constructor and then call A's constructor through it.

But this gets dirty as number of elements go on increasing. What is a better(maybe with less no of arguments?) way to achieve this?

Comment: You should avoid an extensive list of parameters. Think about you architecture. If you need all this data, construct appropriate classes to hold the data and use it as parameter.

Comment: If you face the issue of having too many arguments (or fields), you might want to think about refactoring steps. Maybe the code should be split into several classes?